# DBMS_XMLSTore.insertXML with a value that is XML

Tags: xml, database, oracle, plsql

I have an xml doc that looks like this:

```
<TableRowsets>
    <Table Rows="1" Name="'MyTableName'">
        <ROWSET>
            <ROW>
                <Column1>0</Column1>
                <Column2>0</Column2>
                <Column3>
                    <Config>
                        <SubConfig>
                            ...
                        </SubConfig>
                    </Config>
                </Column3>
            </ROW>
        </ROWSET>
    </Table>
</TableRowsets>
```

Where Column3 contains xml that I want to copy as the value. Column3 is a CLOB column.

I'm calling DBMS_XMLStore like this:

```
PROCEDURE XML_INSERT(in_xml IN CLOB)
IS
  v_context DBMS_XMLStore.ctxType;
  v_rows            NUMBER := 0;
  v_full_table_name VARCHAR2(61);
BEGIN
  IF (in_xml IS NOT NULL) THEN
    FOR c IN
    (SELECT extractvalue(VALUE(xmlseq), 'Table/@Name')    AS TABLE_NAME,
      extract(VALUE(xmlseq), 'Table/ROWSET').getClobVal() AS xml_clob
    FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(extract(XMLTYPE(in_xml), 'TableRowsets/Table'))) xmlseq
    )
    LOOP
      v_full_table_name := PKG_XML.GET_CURRENT_SCHEMA ||'.'|| c.Table_Name;
      BEGIN
        v_context := DBMS_XMLStore.newcontext(v_full_table_name);
        v_rows := DBMS_XMLStore.insertXML(v_context, c.xml_clob);
        DBMS_XMLStore.closecontext(v_context);
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```

However I get the following error:

```
ORA-19200: Invalid column specification
```

How do I insert values which are xml themselves?

Comment: Please show a more complete set of code.

Comment: I added what I could with exception handling etc removed